# MariaDB slow left join using modified index

Tags: mariadb

I have an old MySQL query to find a free ID that always worked fine (0.0325 seconds). But now I have changed to MariaDB and it's extremely slow (over 30 seconds)

```
SELECT 
   START AS codice
FROM (
    SELECT 
       codice +1 AS START 
    FROM  `clfoco` 
    WHERE 
       SUBSTRING(codice,9) BETWEEN '0000001' AND '9999999' AND codice LIKE '1201__%'
) AS a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        codice
    FROM  `clfoco` 
    WHERE 
        SUBSTRING(codice,9) BETWEEN '0000001' AND '9999999' AND codice LIKE '1201__%'
) AS b ON a.start = b.codice
WHERE b.codice IS NULL 
LIMIT 1
```

"codice" is the primary index

The old database was MySQL *5.1.73* and the new one is MariaDB *5.5.52*.

I have replicated the table(import/export db and data), deleted and recreated the index but the query in the new database is always slow.

I have read answers where the changed index (codice+1) breaks the indexes and force MySQL to scan the whole table, but I dont think this is the case since in the old MySQL database the query is fast.

Any suggestion?

**EDIT**
TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clfoco` (
  `codice` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_anagra` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `descri` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   ....
   ....
   ....
   PRIMARY KEY (`codice`),
  KEY `id_anagra` (`id_anagra`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `descri` (`descri`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Explain with Maria Db

```
| id|select_type|table |type    |possible_keys|key      |key_len|ref |rows  |Extra  
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1 | SIMPLE    |clfoco|range   |PRIMARY      |PRIMARY  |62     |NULL|24549 |Using where; Using index  
| 1 | SIMPLE    |clfoco|index   |PRIMARY      |PRIMARY  |62     |NULL|25182 |Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
```

Explain with Mysql *5.1.73*

```
| id|select_type|table      |type   |possible_keys|key      |key_len|ref |rows  |Extra  
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1 |PRIMARY    |<derived2> |ALL    |NULL         |NULL     |NULL   |NULL|24661  
| 1 |PRIMARY    |<derived3> |ALL    |NULL         |NULL     |NULL   |NULL|24661 |Using where; Not exists
| 3 | DERIVED   |clfoco     |index  |PRIMARY      |PRIMARY  |62     |NULL|25182 |Using where; Using index  
| 2 | DERIVED   |clfoco     |index  |PRIMARY      |PRIMARY  |62     |NULL|25182 |Using where; Using index;
```

**NEW EDIT**
After Rick James suggestion I have changed the query.

```
SELECT  a.codice+1 AS START
    FROM  `clfoco` a
    WHERE codice LIKE '1201__%' 
      AND(substring(b.codice,9) between '0000001' and '9999999')
      AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM  `clfoco`
                WHERE codice LIKE '1201__%' 
                  AND (substring(b.codice,9) between '0000001' and '9999999')
                  AND codice = a.codice+1 )
    LIMIT 1;
```

The execution time on MariaDB is 0.0294 seconds

EXPLAIN EXTENDED:

```
id|select_type       |table |type |possible_keys|key    |key_len|ref |rows  |filtered|Extra
1 |PRIMARY           |a     |range|PRIMARY      |PRIMARY|62     |NULL|24549 |100.00  |Using where; Using index
2 |DEPENDENT SUBQUERY|clfoco|range|PRIMARY      |PRIMARY|62     |NULL|24549 |100.00  |Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1)
```

Comment: indexes aren't useful in queries with `like` and/or function based predicates.

Comment: show output of `explain select ...` on the old and new servers

Comment: `SUBSTRING(codice,9) BETWEEN '0000001' AND '9999999'` -- Don't hide a column in a function; it prevents usage of an index.  Get rid of the clause all together since it adds nothing useful.

Comment: You may have hit a specific case where the Oracle optimizer is doing a better job than MariaDB.  Let's see `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for both.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh - `INDEX(codice)` _can_ be used for this "range":  `codice LIKE '1201__%'`.

Comment: @ysth - the query for extract the first free value in a table with value like 
1201100.00000001, 1201200.000000002, 1201100.000000003 
but without the dot.

Comment: @user2380825 sorry, I was forgetting _ is a metacharacter for like

Answer (score 0):

The subselects seem a little obfuscatory, which is always dangerous, because even if it doesn't confuse the optimizer now, it may in a future version (as seems to have happened).  I would have written this, with no subselects:

```
select a.codice+1 as codice
from clfoco a
left join clfoco b
    on b.codice=a.codice+1
    and (substring(b.codice,9) between '0000001' and '9999999')
    and b.codice like '1201__%'
where b.codice is null
and (substring(a.codice,9) between '0000001' and '9999999')
and a.codice like '1201__%'
limit 1;
```

Does this confuse the optimizer less?

From the explain you added of the NOT EXISTS version, it looks like it is using the `like '1201__%'` for indexing the dependent subquery when it shouldn't.  Try this:

```
select a.codice+1 as codice
from clfoco a
left join clfoco b on b.codice=a.codice+1
where b.codice is null
and (substring(a.codice,9) between '0000001' and '9999999')
and a.codice like '1201__%'
and (substring(a.codice+1,9) between '0000001' and '9999999')
and a.codice+1 like '1201__%'
limit 1;
```

Comment: codice is a varchar(20) with value of multiple length and 0 leading.
(es: 2000512, 0012445, 1201110, 12111000000001)

Comment: @user2380825 could you give my query a try and let me know how it works (and if it doesn't what the explain says)

Comment: my query is equivalent to Rick James's except that he leaves out the `substring...between` bit (which may or may not be needed by you; I'm assuming it is so left it in) and he uses NOT EXISTS while I use the equivalent LEFT JOIN+WHERE ... IS NULL which always has proved faster for me.  I only use EXISTS/NOT EXISTS where there are multiple such clauses and more than one one-to-many relationship.

Comment: hi, your query is faster then mine, 12 seconds on MariaDB but it is far slower then MySql

Comment: @user2380825 what does the explain say?  things that might help (depending where the indexes are going wrong): making it `select straight_join ...` or adding `use index (whateverthecodiceindexnameis)` after `clfoco a` and/or `clfoco b`

Comment: I have edited the question with your query and the EXPLAIN. still I don't understand why the execution time is so different between MariaDb and MySQL

Comment: I see Rick James query but not mine.  With his it looks like it is using the like condition for indexing both sides of the join.  I'll edit my query to try to avoid that.  I doubt this is a difference between mariadb and mysql, you'd probably see the same problem in mysql 5.5.  The query optimizer changes over time to try to do a better job; since it involves guesswork, that means some of the time it will change to do a worse job.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.codice+1 AS START
    FROM  `clfoco` a
    WHERE codice LIKE '1201__%'
      AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM  `clfoco`
                WHERE codice LIKE '1201__%'
                  AND codice = a.codice+1 )
    LIMIT 1;
```

Notes:

- `EXISTS` may optimize better.  (But your versions are quite old.)
- `SUBSTRING` gets in the way of index usage.
- The `SUBSTRING` check seems to be useless.
- `codice` needs to be `VARCHAR`, else `LIKE` will be problematical.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: Hmmm... That is interesting.  2 lines in `EXPLAIN` for 3 `SELECTs`.  Please also provide the output from `SHOW WARNINGS;` done immediately after `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...;`  I suspect that there is a significant query rewrite going on.

Comment: Meanwhile, was my formulation 'correct' and faster?

Comment: your query is wrong (but very fast), the result is 12010001 while it should be 1201100000001. i need to find the progressive of a number like 121XXXYYYYYYYYYYY in a table with number lik 121010, 121100, 121200, 121200000000001 (the first 8 numbers are the "tipology", while the next are the user ID.

EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...; SHOW WARNINGS; done in the same query with PhpMyadmin. no row found.

Comment: #Rick James - changed a little your query  as 
`SELECT  a.codice+1 AS START
    FROM  `clfoco` a
    WHERE codice LIKE '1201__%' AND (substring(a.codice,9) between '0000001' and '9999999')
      AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM  `clfoco`
                WHERE codice LIKE '1201__%' AND (substring(a.codice,9) between '0000001' and '9999999')
                  AND codice = a.codice+1 )
    LIMIT 1;
`